# PHP, my sql connection to database for login

Tags: php

i need to confirm login using Php and mysql. My codes keep bringing 'username and password not correct even when it is. Please where did i get it wrong.

HTML code looks like this

[image]

PHP code looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7phTJ.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: Add your code here in a copyable form, and take out your credentials, please.

Comment: you're doing the Password/User authentication entirely wrong. Read up on [password hashing](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/).

Comment: also your code is vulnerable to Sql Injections. You can read here: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue 1 : $user_name = $_POST['username']; you have used single quotes wrongly . Same for password in the screen shot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlUyR.jpg

issue 2 : mysqli_query($CONNECTIONHANDLER, $QUERY) but you are missing connectionhandler.

Full Code changes :

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass_word']);


$rs = mysqli_query($con, "Select username, pass_word from verify where username = '%s' and pass_word = '%s'", $username, $upassword);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

if($check_user>0){
    echo "Logged in / valid user ";
} else {
    echo "username / password incorrect";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
`'$_POST[username]'` to `$_POST['username']` and same goes for password.

You are actually assigned string values instead of getting them from `$_POST` array

Comment: @masquellett did that work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove simple quote

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass_word'];
```

Keep in mind that POST input should **ALWAYS** be sanitized to avoid injection

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong. Also you just posted your username and password on the internet.
The query is redundant. You should just check for the presence of a user with such username and password (for example Select Count(*) from...)
the second control you are doing is superfluous. Also you are declaring a variable inside a while and you are trying to access those values from outside of it.

Also there are some syntactic errors like quotes and stuff that other users already suggested.